# How do I pass more than two variables in applescript do shell script?

Tags: applescript, sh

I tried this:

```
do shell script "curl -A  " & quoted form of useragent & " quoted form of urlst"
```

However, this thinks the `quoted form of urlst` is shell scripting.

I also tried this:

```
do shell script "curl -A  " & quoted form of useragent & quoted form of urlst
```

But now it just says that there was no URL specified, so it can't read the variable.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer what you should do is:

```
do shell script "curl -A  " & quoted form of useragent & space & quoted form of urlst
```

The shell has an unique way of handling text. Normally bash reads data until it meets a separator (default: space, tab or return). The quote is a switch that turns on or off how the remaining data should be interpreted. When it reads a quote it switches its substitution mode on or off. When it's on (by default) special characters keep their meaning and when it is off special characters has no meaning at all. So `'hello world!'` and `hello' 'world!` is the same string in bash because only the space is a special character where the first quote turns substitution off and the second quote turns it back on. Before reaching the end of the line the substitution mode needs to be turned on again so it can find the end of the line. On your case the string `'safari'` directly followed by `'http://www.stackoverflow.com'` will be considered as one complete string. So when passing multiple arguments to bash you need make sure it is separated by a space when the substitution mode is on.